# Calculate duration time of each phaseId

Tags: php

I have the following array :

```
array (size=8)
  0 => 
    array (size=5)
      'entity_id' => int 571962
      'time' => int 1671101084788
      'time to datetime' => string '2022-12-15 11:44:44' (length=19)
      'PhaseId_new' => string 'Close' (length=5)
      'PhaseId_old' => string 'Accept' (length=6)
  1 => 
    array (size=5)
      'entity_id' => int 571962
      'time' => int 1671100537178
      'time to datetime' => string '2022-12-15 11:35:37' (length=19)
      'PhaseId_new' => string 'Accept' (length=6)
      'PhaseId_old' => string 'Fulfill' (length=7)
  2 => 
    array (size=5)
      'entity_id' => int 571962
      'time' => int 1671100012012
      'time to datetime' => string '2022-12-15 11:26:52' (length=19)
      'PhaseId_new' => string 'Fulfill' (length=7)
      'PhaseId_old' => string 'Review' (length=6)
  3 => 
    array (size=5)
      'entity_id' => int 571962
      'time' => int 1671099984979
      'time to datetime' => string '2022-12-15 11:26:24' (length=19)
      'PhaseId_new' => string 'Review' (length=6)
      'PhaseId_old' => string 'Accept' (length=6)
  4 => 
    array (size=5)
      'entity_id' => int 571962
      'time' => int 1671099802675
      'time to datetime' => string '2022-12-15 11:23:22' (length=19)
      'PhaseId_new' => string 'Accept' (length=6)
      'PhaseId_old' => string 'Fulfill' (length=7)
  5 => 
    array (size=5)
      'entity_id' => int 571962
      'time' => int 1671027321749
      'time to datetime' => string '2022-12-14 15:15:21' (length=19)
      'PhaseId_new' => string 'Fulfill' (length=7)
      'PhaseId_old' => string 'Approve' (length=7)
  6 => 
    array (size=5)
      'entity_id' => int 571962
      'time' => int 1671011168777
      'time to datetime' => string '2022-12-14 10:46:08' (length=19)
      'PhaseId_new' => string 'Approve' (length=7)
      'PhaseId_old' => string 'Log' (length=3)
  7 => 
    array (size=5)
      'entity_id' => int 571962
      'time' => int 1671011166077
      'time to datetime' => string '2022-12-14 10:46:06' (length=19)
      'PhaseId_new' => string 'Log' (length=3)
      'PhaseId_old' => null
```

I regrouped every child array by `entity_id` using :

```
$result = array();
foreach ($data as $element) {
    //var_dump($element);
    $result[$element['entity_id']][] = $element;
}
```

Which output me :

```
array (size=1)
  571962 => 
    array (size=8)
      0 => 
        array (size=5)
          'entity_id' => int 571962
          'time' => int 1671101084788
          'time to datetime' => string '2022-12-15 11:44:44' (length=19)
          'PhaseId_new' => string 'Close' (length=5)
          'PhaseId_old' => string 'Accept' (length=6)
      1 => 
        array (size=5)
          'entity_id' => int 571962
          'time' => int 1671100537178
          'time to datetime' => string '2022-12-15 11:35:37' (length=19)
          'PhaseId_new' => string 'Accept' (length=6)
          'PhaseId_old' => string 'Fulfill' (length=7)
      2 => 
        array (size=5)
          'entity_id' => int 571962
          'time' => int 1671100012012
          'time to datetime' => string '2022-12-15 11:26:52' (length=19)
          'PhaseId_new' => string 'Fulfill' (length=7)
          'PhaseId_old' => string 'Review' (length=6)
      3 => 
        array (size=5)
          'entity_id' => int 571962
          'time' => int 1671099984979
          'time to datetime' => string '2022-12-15 11:26:24' (length=19)
          'PhaseId_new' => string 'Review' (length=6)
          'PhaseId_old' => string 'Accept' (length=6)
      4 => 
        array (size=5)
          'entity_id' => int 571962
          'time' => int 1671099802675
          'time to datetime' => string '2022-12-15 11:23:22' (length=19)
          'PhaseId_new' => string 'Accept' (length=6)
          'PhaseId_old' => string 'Fulfill' (length=7)
      5 => 
        array (size=5)
          'entity_id' => int 571962
          'time' => int 1671027321749
          'time to datetime' => string '2022-12-14 15:15:21' (length=19)
          'PhaseId_new' => string 'Fulfill' (length=7)
          'PhaseId_old' => string 'Approve' (length=7)
      6 => 
        array (size=5)
          'entity_id' => int 571962
          'time' => int 1671011168777
          'time to datetime' => string '2022-12-14 10:46:08' (length=19)
          'PhaseId_new' => string 'Approve' (length=7)
          'PhaseId_old' => string 'Log' (length=3)
      7 => 
        array (size=5)
          'entity_id' => int 571962
          'time' => int 1671011166077
          'time to datetime' => string '2022-12-14 10:46:06' (length=19)
          'PhaseId_new' => string 'Log' (length=3)
          'PhaseId_old' => null
```

Now I need to calculate the time duration of each phase (Log, Approve, Fulfill, Accept, Review).

For exemple :

Log : `1671011168777 - 1671011166077 = 2700`

Approve : `1671027321749 - 1671011168777 = 16152972`

Fulfill : `(1671100537178 - 1671100012012) + (1671099802675 - 1671027321749) = 73006092`

Accept : `(1671101084788 - 1671100537178) + (1671099984979 - 1671099802675) = 729914`

Review : `1671100012012 - 1671099984979 = 27033`

I'm able to parse each phase using :

```
foreach($result as $key => $val){
    //var_dump($key);
    foreach($val as $key2 => $val2){
        if($val2['PhaseId_new'] == 'Fulfill' or $val2['PhaseId_old'] == 'Fulfill'){

           // var_dump($val2);
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't have a clear idea on how to calculate the duration of every phase.

An expected result would look like :

```
array (size=1)
  571962 => 
    array (size=8)
          'Log' => int 2700
          'Approve' => int 16152972
          'Fulfill' => int 73006092
          'Accept' => int 729914
          'Review' => int 27033
```

PHP online : https://onlinephp.io/c/2270e

Workflow :

[image]

Comment: I tried, see: https://onlinephp.io/c/0b94c but the results are shifted. Is that my error, or is the error in the data?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware 'Log' has no PhaseOld, but you calc with that.

Comment: I think it's because ```'PhaseId_new' => string 'Log' (length=3)
          'PhaseId_old' => null```

Comment: Yes, that's true, but my problem is: How does the "Log" entry know where to look to do it's calculation? It's in the "Approve" entry. But there the "Log" phase_id is called "old". So, I don't get how these phases work. I can compute it more correctly like this: https://onlinephp.io/c/cf0c3

Comment: But, of course, I don't get your results. These phases are a mystery.

Comment: Log is the first phase of my workflow, that's why ```'PhaseId_old' => null```

Comment: You have two times 'Fulfill' as new in your array. Is that right?

Comment: As far as I can tell there is some hidden logic to how you want these phase times computed, which you haven't explained in your question. Therefore I cannot answer your question at this time.

Comment: @Foobar Yes it's right, sometime, users reject the answers so we go back to this phase, it can happened several times

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I added a picture of my workflow, maybe it will give a better context

Comment: Ah, that workflow was indeed missing. It's quite complex, as I already assumed. I now also get that the duration of the "Log" phase is either from "Log" to "Approve" or from "Log" to "Abandon", both are called the duration of the "Log" phase. It also explains the additions of time periods.

Comment: To calculate the duration, I need to calculate the difference between the entry and exit of the phase, if it appear several times so I sum the total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this took me far longer than I wanted, but I got a result. First the code:

```
$entityPhases = [];
foreach ($data as $element) {
    $entityPhases[$element['entity_id']][] = $element;
}

$durations = [];
$oldPhases = [];
foreach ($entityPhases as $phases) {
    foreach(array_reverse($phases) as $phase) {
        if ($phase['PhaseId_old']) {
            $oldPhaseName = $phase['PhaseId_old'];
            $duration = $phase['time'] - $oldPhases[$oldPhaseName]['time'];
            $durations[$oldPhaseName] = ($durations[$oldPhaseName] ?? 0) + $duration;
        }   
        $oldPhases[$phase['PhaseId_new']] = $phase;
    }
}

print_r($durations);
```

See: https://onlinephp.io/c/92d7f

The result is:

```
Array
(
    [Log] => 2700
    [Approve] => 16152972
    [Fulfill] => 73006092
    [Accept] => 729914
    [Review] => 27033
)
```

Now the explanation:

First of all, your data array seems up-side-down, so I resort it with `array_reverse()`. The *assumption* here is that there is a logical order.

Since it might be necessary to add up several periods, I use a array, called `$durations` to add these up.

Then in the inner loop, if there is an old phase id, I can compute the duration and add it. At the end I remember the old phase, because I need it in the next iteration of the loop.

I also renamed a lot of stuff to have names that convey the content of the variables.

Comment: Note that I remember whole `$oldPhases`, but in practice only the `time` is used. You could only remember that, which would save some memory.

Comment: Oh, and I also don't keep the entity id. That's something I'll leave for you. 

Comment: Is it possible to always sort by time DESC ?

Comment: @executable I assume you're talking about the original `$data` array? Yes, that is possible. Have a look at [usort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), if allows you to create a user-defined comparison function for the sort.

Answer (score 1):

Try someting like this.

```
//group by entity_id
$data_grouped = [];
foreach($data as $element) {
  $data_grouped[$element['entity_id']][] = $element;
}

$entity_phases = [];
//get all phases and their times
foreach ($data_grouped as $entity_id => $elements) {
  foreach ($elements as $element) {
    if ($element['PhaseId_new']) {
      $entity_phases[$entity_id][$element['PhaseId_new']][] = $element['time'];
    }
    if ($element['PhaseId_old']) {
      $entity_phases[$entity_id][$element['PhaseId_old']][] = $element['time'];
    }
  }
}

$result = [];
//iterate all phases and calculate time diffs
foreach ($entity_phases as $entity_id => $phases) {
  foreach ($phases as $key => $values) {
    if (!isset($result[$entity_id][$key])) {
      $result[$entity_id][$key] = 0;
    }
    //iterate in chunks of two elements
    foreach (array_chunk($values, 2) as $value) {
      //continue if only one value is found (e.g. for "Close")
      if (!isset($value[1])) {
        continue;
      }
      $result[$entity_id][$key] = $result[$entity_id][$key] + $value[0] - $value[1];
    }
  }
}
var_dump($result);
```

This gives you:

```
array(1) {
  [571962]=>
  array(6) {
    ["Close"]=>
    int(0)
    ["Accept"]=>
    int(729914)
    ["Fulfill"]=>
    int(73006092)
    ["Review"]=>
    int(27033)
    ["Approve"]=>
    int(16152972)
    ["Log"]=>
    int(2700)
  }
}
```

Comment: I group them by entity_id, because I retreive others id too

Comment: I updated my answer with group by entity_id